# Какой функционал у elephant io и как им пользоваться?

Tags: php, socket.io

Писал чат для сайта, так как весь сайт написан на PHP пришлось каким то образом соединять php-страницы с socket.io, для этого решил использовать elephant.io, но если раньше было хоть что-то понятно, то теперь мне вообще не понятно, что делать дальше, и по правильному ли пути я вообще пошел.

---

Вот у меня есть небольшой код на странице ( имею крайне слабое представление о том, что в нем происходит )

```
use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

$_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();

if ($_COOKIE) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($_SESSION) {
        if (!$_SESSION['user_id']) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
    }
}
//Это тестовая страница, поэтому здесь user_id я задаю таким образом, в дальнейшем он будет браться из БД сгенерированным
$_SESSION['user_id'] = rand(1, 99);

$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:1337', [
    'headers' => [
        'X-My-Header: websocket rocks',
        'Authorization: Bearer 12b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i',
        'user_id:'.$_SESSION['user_id']
    ]
]));

$client->initialize();
$client->emit('broadcast', ['foo' => 'bar']);
$client->close();
```

Далее у меня идет код HTML страницы с блоками для отправки сообщений( Думаю его сюда вставлять нет смысла ).
Раньше на странице клиента у меня был скрипт в котором я подключался к сокету `var socket = io.connect();`(поправьте если ошибаюсь), и далее после нажатия на кнопку *отправить сообщение* у меня срабатывал скрипт по вызову функции с таким содержимым `socket.emit('sendMess', {name:$name.val(),mes:$mes.val(),nameID:socketName});` После чего данный код обрабатывался на стороне скрипта сокета.

---

Что меняется с elephant? Зачем он вообще нужен? Как сделать аналогичный алгоритм но с его применением? (Я жутко запутался в том, что делаю)

Comment: я бы поставил просто node socket.io сервер рядом и ходил с браузера на него без  php;

Если браузер откажется ходить одновременно на php и node, можно попробовать
разобраться с CORS или поставить nginx/haproxy, который по пути на них запросы распределит