# Как безопасно передать данные PHP сессии в socket io?

Tags: javascript, php, socket.io

Пролог:

К несчастью на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147992/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%83-elephant-io-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) по функционалу PHP elephant я ответа так и не получил, поэтому пришлось выкручиваться.

---

Написал пару функций по отправке сообщений на базисе socket.io. Из-за того, что весь сайт написан на PHP - идентификация пользователя ведется также с помощью сессии PHP, следовательно дабы устанавливать связи в чате между пользователями каким-то образом данное значение сессии как-то надо передать на сторону сокета.

У меня появилась вполне предсказуемая идея, использовать на стороне клиента ajax GET запрос для получения этого значения сессии. И с этим возник вопрос: Безопасно ли это и есть ли более адекватные альтернативы?

Comment: В чем проблема создать отдельный сокет сервер на NodeJS и подключаться к нему? Попробуйте написать сервер таким образом, чтобы он отправлял запрос на API PHP и пересылал это дело клиенту на сокет.

Comment: @MoloF, сокет сервер итак написан на Node JS и лежит отдельно от всего, надо было уточнить в вопросе. А каким образом идентифицировать получателя сообщения? Нам же нужны данные не только отправителя, но и получателя сообщения. ( Я в этой теме дилетант )

Comment: Если вы реализуете чат, мой вам совет - используйте [centrifugo](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifugo). Там уже всё что надо есть + js библиотека для listen'a каналов и .т.п.

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо! Действительно обширная библиотека по которой МНОГО, как оказалось, примеров.

Comment: Это сарказм был? :) Не библиотека это, а сервер. Примеров достаточно, надо просто уметь искать

Comment: @InDevX, не думал, что и в интернете меня заподозрят в сарказме. Нет, это был не сарказм. Примеров действительно много, чему я был приятно удивлен ( сравниваю с elephant.io по которому 3-4 жалкие странички в гугл )